# Why does storing session data in my php script mess with my Ajax script?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

right i have a form, it uses ajax to check the if all fields have been filled in and if not say which ones haven't without reloading the page. If all the fields have values it tghen redirects the user to a payment page.

This worked fine, but i want to save some data a session so i can retrieve the users information from the database on the payment page and send it off to moneybookers for payment.

Anyways, when i use this like of code:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $result->email;
```

(The email address is held in an object) It seems to break my Ajax, it doesn't seem to return any validation or redirect if the form is filled out.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Maybe PHP sessions conflict with Ajax somehow.... maybe....? I'm not an expert with Javascript so i really don't know what to look for.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Is result populated prior to its use?

Comment: @SOliver Yeah it is populated for sure, otherwise that part of the script would not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_dump($result->email);` to make sure it contains whatever value you are expecting it to be.

For debugging AJAX, you can use Chrome's built in console's

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize a session with session_start() in your script?

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $result->email;
```

Comment: Yeah session_start(); works fine, but when i put some data in there it seems to kick up a fuss.

Comment: Configure the php to put all errors in error.log file and see if it contains any errors while you do an AJAX request. Because seems like problem is not in a session but somewhere else (You can actually get some error/worning/notice) from PHP and it brakes your AJAX response. Or try to retrieve from AJAX a plain text and alert() it to see what is produced on PHP side